# Buttons align/dock in NavigationView navigationBar in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, navigationbar

I have a Navigation view, in navigation view i want to put a button at the right side of navigationBar

> here is sencha fiddle
>   [My Fiddle is here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1shp)

you can see my menu button i want that button at the right side

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `align: 'right'` to the button config object. Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1si1).